From here I was able to fetch only the text with face. The styles we have here are not coming
I am using it with Nextjs tsx..
Github Link

{
\_id: ObjectId('66d88efc48f48a786e4a683b'),
title: 'Name of Organization: Dhaka Ice Cream Industries Limited. (Polar Ice Cream)',
slug: 'Position: Assistant Audit Office. (Sales Audit)',

content: '{"root":{"children":\[{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":1,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"Elevate Your Supply ","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"Chain Career","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":3,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":" to the next level","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":" with the Chartered Supply Chain Professionals™, designa","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":16,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"tion program!","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"Unlock new ","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #7ed321;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"opportunities and el","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":1,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #7ed321;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"evate you","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":1,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"r","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":" expertise wi","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #ff3636;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"th Chartered Supply Ch","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"ain P","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #fd3f3f;","text":"rofessionals title to your name! ","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[\],"direction":null,"format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"Are you ready to take your c","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;font-size: 12px;","text":"areer i","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"n supply chain ma","type":"text","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"nagement to new heig","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"link","version":1,"rel":"noopener","target":null,"title":null,"url":"https://Position: Assistant Audit Office. (Sales Audit)"},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"hts?","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"heading","version":1,"tag":"h2"},{"children":\[\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;font-family: Times New Roman;","text":" Lo","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":32,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;font-family: Times New Roman;","text":"ok no furt","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;font-family: Times New Roman;","text":"her!  Introducing our exclusive \\"Chartered Supply Chain Profes","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"sionals™,\\" ","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"designation program - the key to unlocking unparalleled","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1},{"children":\[{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #000000;background-color: #ffffff;","text":" opportunities in the dyn","type":"text","version":1},{"detail":0,"format":0,"mode":"normal","style":"color: #50e3c2;background-color: #ffffff;","text":"amic world of supply chain!","type":"text","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"paragraph","version":1}\],"direction":"ltr","format":"","indent":0,"type":"root","version":1}}',

    createdAt: ISODate('2024-09-04T16:46:52.508Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-09-04T16:46:52.508Z'),
    __v:  #0

}


It will bring the correct data from the database with the style but I could not do it?
